# Java stream reduce to map

Tags: java, java-stream

I got array list of strings, how could I reduce them to hash map

Input: `[a, b, a, a, c, x]`

Output: `{(a: 3), (b: 1), (c: 1), (x: 1)}`

PS. I searched for this. I need to do that with `reduce` not with frequency counting as in other questions, because my question is a simplified real task.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash No, I need to use reduce, not frequency

Comment: @ЕгорЛебедев - I've cast my vote to reopen it.

Comment: You can do like: `Map<String,Integer> result =  Arrays.stream(str)
                .reduce(new HashMap<>(),
                        (hashMap, e) -> {hashMap.merge(e,1,Integer::sum);return hashMap;},
                        (m, m2) -> {m.putAll(m2);return m;});` however other solutions are more readable and concise.

Comment: @HadiJ Thanks, It is not about readability, I simplified my real task for the question, that is why I asked exactly about reduce. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks @HadiJ for answer

```
Map<String,Integer> result = Arrays.stream(str)
    .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (hashMap, e) -> {
        hashMap.merge(e, 1, Integer::sum);
        return hashMap;
    },
    (m, m2) -> {
        m.putAll(m2);
        return m;
    }
);
```